# CacheException - Error deserializing object - MyBatis and Play

Tags: java, playframework, ibatis, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis with playframework and everything works nicely except:

When I've attempted to use the default cache built in MyBatis (`<cache/>` tag in xml mapper files), upon retrieving a cached select statement I get this stacktrace.

If I run the same statements in a unit test (or another application without playframework involved) everything works fine.

So, my guess it has something to do the way playframework loads/compiles the classes some sort of classloader issue.

The directory layout of my project looks something like this (relevant bits):

```
app
  controllers
  data // xml mapping files and java interfaces for ibatis
       // & a class that returns a SqlSessionFactory
    domain // Pojos for SQL results (e.g. User.java)
  models
  views
lib // here is myibatis jar file
(...) // the rest of the standard play framework project
```

The model method that throws the exception is this:

```
  public static UserAuthentication findAuthenticatonIdentity(UserId userId){
    SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = IbatisSessionFactory.getSqlMapper();
    SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    AuthMapper authMapper = session.getMapper(AuthMapper.class);

    UserAuthentication ua = authMapper.selectByUserId(userId); // line 162
    session.close();
    return ua;
  }
```

And UserAuthentication implements Serializable!

And here is the stacktrace:

```
Execution exception (In /app/models/UserModel.java around line 162)
PersistenceException occured : 
 ### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.domain.UserAuthentication
 ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.domain.UserAuthentication

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.domain.UserAuthentication
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.domain.UserAuthentication
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.domain.UserAuthentication
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.domain.UserAuthentication
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:102)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:94)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:58)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:90)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
    at $Proxy8.selectByUserId(Unknown Source)
    at models.UserModel.findAuthenticatonIdentity(UserModel.java:162)
    at controllers.securesocial.MySecureSocial.checkAccess(MySecureSocial.java:97)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:504)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.handleBefores(ActionInvoker.java:322)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:142)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error deserializing object.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.domain.UserAuthentication
    at org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.SerializedCache.deserialize(SerializedCache.java:94)
    at org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.SerializedCache.getObject(SerializedCache.java:50)
    at org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.LoggingCache.getObject(LoggingCache.java:50)
    at org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.SynchronizedCache.getObject(SynchronizedCache.java:55)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:72)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:100)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.domain.UserAuthentication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:603)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.SerializedCache.deserialize(SerializedCache.java:91)
    ... 18 more
```

UserAuthentication.java

```
public class UserAuthentication implements Serializable {

  private int id;
  private String authId;
  private String secret;
  private String token; // Oauth1 token
  private String accessToken; // Oauth2 request token
  private String displayName;
  private String authMethod;
  private String provider;
  private String email;
  private String avatarUrl;
  private Date lastAccess;
  private String password;
  private boolean emailVerified;
  private int userId;
  private String activationUuid;
  private Date activationExpiry;

  // + getters & setters
}
```

UserId.java

```
public class UserId implements java.io.Serializable {
    /**
     * The id the user has in a external service.
     */
    public String id;

    /**
     * The provider this user belongs to.
     */
    public ProviderType provider; // simple enum
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I think I was wrong - this is not a name collision but rather a classloader problem.

Play uses a dynamic classloading mechanism to detect changes to the source code and enhance methods through bytecode injection.  http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_frm/thread/359736394ae27902/98445c557833036c

I think the problem may be that MyBatis is using the regular class loader - so can't find the classes that are loaded via Play's mechanism.  When you put the source into the Play directory, MyBatis is then using the Play classloader.

Here are some options:

1) Compile your domain objects into a JAR file.  Include that jar in your project: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/b54e4e25ae49161b

2) Force MyBatis to use the Play classloader - somewhere before any mybatis calls

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Play.classloader);
```

http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/f4789ee5c20609af/d1412a914dc06851?#d1412a914dc06851

Still seems like a hack, but perhaps it keeps your application source size down.

3) Ensure your classes are loaded before the calls to MyBatis.  So, in this case.

```
Class.forName("data.domain.UserAuthentication");
Class.forName("data.domain.UserId");
```

Which seems far worse of a hack.

I hope one of those options works for you.

Comment: I've added the extra info you required.

Comment: based on your fix, it sounds like it might be a class name clash.  by compiling them in the project, you change the order.

Comment: how many Serializable classes do you see (presuming you are using eclipse) if you use "Open Type" (ctrl + shift + T in eclipse).

Comment: there are 2: `java.io.Serializable` & `sunw.io.Serializable`

Comment: Sorry for not following up on this earlier but I didn't get any notifications on your latest edits. I got it working using solution #1. The other two didn't seem to work - or I'm doing something wrong. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record this issue was fixed in MyBatis 3.1.1

http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=530

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** With patch #530 included in the current release everything works as expected.

Play 1.x users might be interested in [MyBatisPlay](http://www.playframework.org/modules/mybatisplay) module, which I'm maintaining. This is very useful in development because it will reset the session factory when a change occurs in java source files or xml mappers configuration, thus avoiding the need to restart the web app.

**Original post:**
I found a workaround:

- if I copy the source files for MyBatis under app directory (i'm letting play framework compile them as usually) and remove the ibatis precompiled jar from lib directory, it works as expected.

However, I'm looking for a better solution that doesn't sound like a hack :)

Thanks!

Comment: @DiegoLopez Sorry, I should have updated this info here. I'm actually the one who submitted the patch for issue #530. So, yes it's working properly now :). Thanks!